# Looking for a way to access Global-variables from another AddIn

Tags: c#, .net, excel, user-defined-functions, excel-interop

So, I'm working on an Excel AddIn (normal VSTO project) that uses a RibbonBar and some External DLL. 
Because it is required to import some User-Defined-Functions(UDF) in Excel, I read that you only can do so by registrating it with COM, I did so with an Interface for the functions etc.
I did the registration as it was shown at https://theofficecontext.com/2013/06/08/update-creating-excel-udfs-in-c/ 
The registration worked fine and my imported functions can be called inside Excel.
I use some Dialogs to let the user set some variables that are used for the UDF's and I found out that those two things are managed in separate AddIn objects.

And thats the problem. Because they are two different Objects, all the stuff I entered with the dialogs can't be accessed by the UDF's.

OnConnection() is called from inside Excel, when the UDF's get loaded by interacting with the worksheed.

```cs
namespace myExcelAddin
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    { 
        public static int iUser = 0;
        // .. some other static variables

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
          // some startup work 
        }
     }
}

namespace myExcelAddin
{
  [ComVisible(true)]
  public interface IFunctions
  {
       // ... some functions
  }

    [ComVisible(true)]
    [GuidAttribute("1D3001F4-5307-49A6-98F2-B3B76B3D0AA3"),
    ProgId("myExcelAddin.Functions"),
    ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None),
    ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IFunctions))]

  public partial class Connect : Object, Extensibility.IDTExtensibility2,      IFunctions
  {
       // ... implementation of interface functions
  }

public void OnConnection(object application, Extensibility.ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref System.Array custom)
 {
       // get a reference to the instance of the add-in
       Application = application as Excel.Application;
       thisAddIn = addInInst;
  }

  [ComRegisterFunctionAttribute]
  public static void RegisterFunction(Type type)
  {
      //... registration work
  }

  [ComUnregisterFunctionAttribute]
  public static void UnregisterFunction(Type type)
  {
     // ... unregistration work
  }
}
```

So is there a possibility to get the stuff the user entered?
Because Globals for both is also handled differently ...

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be complex problem but few ideas comes to my mind:

1) Registry - HKEY_CURRENT_USER if amount of data is rather small

2) Put it into file and read the file from other AddIn

3) This looks most realiable - use Excel to transport data - i.e. create hidden worksheet and just put data into it - but it could be hard if you don't want to modify existing workbook

Comment: Yes it was indeed a complex problem. Still have no real good solution that came to my mind. Because I was not sure if everyone can write into the registry using the Addin, I decided to ship around the problem by adding a .config file and redirected the default setting path of my UDF addin to that file.

Comment: To current user user has always permission.